# What is the best way to protect a Google cloud function against a DDOS attack

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin, ddos

I'm new in network and I want to protect the layer 7 of a Google cloud function. I've found [cloud armour](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/?hl=En) that allow to create an allow/deny ip list for an https load balancer. Also [Cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com/) that propose an illimited ddos mitigation.

My questions are:

1 - Is it possible to use cloud armour when my users ip list is dynamic/(unknown in advance) ? If so, can somebody point me to an informative link please?

2 - When my cloud function is behind a load balancer, can I access it again with it's normal url?

3 - Do somebody know better ways to achieve my goal with a priority to Google cloud plateforme solutions.

Thank for your help and sorry if my English is bad.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not an expert, but I believe that you can't define a policy to a dynamic list. Although you can create a custom logging metric + Stackdriver alert to invoke a script to update your cloud armor policy [ [1](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/configure-security-policies) ] (using webhooks[ [2](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/support/notification-options) ]).

About your second question, you can't put google cloud function behind a load balance.

To conclude you can create protection about DDOS attack but Google already provides a tremendous and transparency protection against it [ [3](https://cloud.google.com/files/GCPDDoSprotection-04122016.pdf) ].